# Responsive web design

Tags: media-queries, responsive-design

I have 3 css files with me:

1. skeleton.css
2. base.css
3. layout.css

What I want to do is make my web site responsive.

For this, this css files are going to be used in order to make my site responsive.

I have gone through all of the 3 css and it contains media queries and many more.

I want to now that how to use or embed existing style.css with media queries?
how to apply media queries ?
and where to aply media queries?

Answer (score 0):

Skeleton is a responsive CSS framework that works really well. Your best bet is to review the code on Dave's website at http://www.getskeleton.com/ - the code he has posted is very helpful and will give you a great start. I started with Skeleton (http://72t.net) and later moved to Bootstrap.

With all that said, depending on how the code was originally written, it may be a real task trying to convert an existing website to a responsive design. I have now done (or am doing) 4  responsive sites - in each case I found it easier to start from scratch - the original sites were done in Asp.Net with its appropriate bloat. the new sites are html5, CSS, JQuery and Ajax.

Comment: When you say start from scratch.... do you mean building the media queries in yourself or start afresh with one of the frameworks?

Comment: I try never to recreate the wheel - I should have been more clear. What I meant was using Skeleton (1 site) and Bootstrap (3 sites), I rebuilt the website from scratch using their CSS frameworks. It was easier than trying to convert an existing fixed dimension site to a responsive framework. Because a lot of the server side code was already in Dll format, it was really just recreating the html part of web pages and moving from partial page post backs (Asp.Net) to ajax.

Comment: @Gfw: Is skeleton framework compatible in ie8? Which is the best framework to create responsive webpage which is compatible with all major browsers including ie8?